# Faster thread safe function for splitting Strings in C

Tags: multithreading, split, thread-safety

What is the faster thread safe function that I can use in C for read from file and splitting the string?
Right now I am using fgets in a combination with strtok_r but I want to know if there is any faster way.

Note that the files I am reading have several Gigabytes size

Thank you

Comment: You need to improve/clarify your question. "for read from file and splitting the string", I'm not sure what you are asking here? What are you reading from the file? What string are you splitting?

Comment: I am reading a line from a file. ex: "185|364" and i want to split it to : id1=185, id2=364

Comment: If all the numbers are the same length, then just move the pointer +4 in and memcpy the 3 numbers. Otherwise your going to have to calculate the length manually by iterating over each character .